# Lookup JSONField from DB without loading it as an object

Tags: python, django

I have a JSONField in one of my django models. I now want to write a very fast view function that is just meant to return that field as application/json content. However, I'm noticing that with a JSONField the string stored in the DB is automatically loaded into an object so I have to re-pack it into a string to send to the client. Is there a way to have the JSONField skip loading the string into an object?

Comment: show what you are doing now to send it to the client. It helps to have something concrete to advise on other than hypothetical. Which database backend are you using? Does PostgreSQL's jsonb assist you? See PostgreSQL users under:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield - Is python the bottleneck in your fast view?